# Composer update says nothing to install or update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6

- Laravel Version: 5.6.35
- PHP Version: 7.1.20
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL v5.5.61-0ubuntu0.14.04.1

#### Description:

At the time of this question, the latest version of Laravel is 5.6.37 - released 2 days ago i.e., 2nd September, 2018.

I already have a project that I am working on. On running `composer update`, I always get the following:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

This started only after I updated my laravel project to 5.6.35.

This is not the case when I install a new laravel project. On new installation, the latest version of laravel, i.e., 5.6.37 gets downloaded.

Below is my composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "spinen/laravel-mail-assertions": "^0.3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.1",
        "codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer": "^0.19.13",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Larammerce\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

1. Have a Laravel project <= 5.6.35
2. Run composer update

I don't know where and what should be the mistake that I must have committed.

#### I have tried the following

1. Running `composer dump-autoload && composer update`
2. Deleting `composer.lock` file and `vendor` directory. Then running `composer update`

But couldn't get my project updated to Laravel version 5.6.37

---

**Update 1**

On running `composer show -i` I got the following:

```
barryvdh/laravel-debugbar             v3.1.5   PHP Debugbar integration for Laravel
codedungeon/php-cli-colors            1.10.7   PHP Package for using color output in CLI commands
codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer    0.19.13  PHPUnit Pretty Result Printer
dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir              0.1      implementation of xdg base directory specification for php
doctrine/inflector                    v1.3.0   Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/instantiator                 1.1.0    A small, lightweight utility to instantiate objects in PHP without invoking their constructors
doctrine/lexer                        v1.0.1   Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
dragonmantank/cron-expression         v2.2.0   CRON for PHP: Calculate the next or previous run date and determine if a CRON expression is due
egulias/email-validator               2.1.5    A library for validating emails against several RFCs
erusev/parsedown                      1.7.1    Parser for Markdown.
fideloper/proxy                       4.0.0    Set trusted proxies for Laravel
filp/whoops                           2.2.0    php error handling for cool kids
fzaninotto/faker                      v1.8.0   Faker is a PHP library that generates fake data for you.
hamcrest/hamcrest-php                 v2.0.0   This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
hassankhan/config                     1.1.0    Lightweight configuration file loader that supports PHP, INI, XML, JSON, and YAML files
jakub-onderka/php-console-color       0.1     
jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter v0.3.2  
laravel/framework                     v5.6.35  The Laravel Framework.
laravel/tinker                        v1.0.7   Powerful REPL for the Laravel framework.
league/flysystem                      1.0.46   Filesystem abstraction: Many filesystems, one API.
maximebf/debugbar                     v1.15.0  Debug bar in the browser for php application
mockery/mockery                       1.1.0    Mockery is a simple yet flexible PHP mock object framework
monolog/monolog                       1.23.0   Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
myclabs/deep-copy                     1.8.1    Create deep copies (clones) of your objects
nesbot/carbon                         1.25.0   A simple API extension for DateTime.
nikic/php-parser                      v4.0.3   A PHP parser written in PHP
nunomaduro/collision                  v2.0.3   Cli error handling for console/command-line PHP applications.
paragonie/random_compat               v9.99.99 PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
phar-io/manifest                      1.0.3    Component for reading phar.io manifest information from a PHP Archive (PHAR)
phar-io/version                       2.0.1    Library for handling version information and constraints
phpdocumentor/reflection-common       1.0.1    Common reflection classes used by phpdocumentor to reflect the code structure
phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock     4.3.0    With this component, a library can provide support for annotations via DocBlocks or otherwise r...
phpdocumentor/type-resolver           0.4.0   
phpspec/prophecy                      1.8.0    Highly opinionated mocking framework for PHP 5.3+
phpunit/php-code-coverage             6.0.7    Library that provides collection, processing, and rendering functionality for PHP code coverage...
phpunit/php-file-iterator             2.0.1    FilterIterator implementation that filters files based on a list of suffixes.
phpunit/php-text-template             1.2.1    Simple template engine.
phpunit/php-timer                     2.0.0    Utility class for timing
phpunit/php-token-stream              3.0.0    Wrapper around PHP's tokenizer extension.
phpunit/phpunit                       7.3.2    The PHP Unit Testing framework.
psr/container                         1.0.0    Common Container Interface (PHP FIG PSR-11)
psr/log                               1.0.2    Common interface for logging libraries
psr/simple-cache                      1.0.1    Common interfaces for simple caching
psy/psysh                             v0.9.7   An interactive shell for modern PHP.
ramsey/uuid                           3.8.0    Formerly rhumsaa/uuid. A PHP 5.4+ library for generating RFC 4122 version 1, 3, 4, and 5 univer...
sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup    1.0.1    Looks up which function or method a line of code belongs to
sebastian/comparator                  3.0.2    Provides the functionality to compare PHP values for equality
sebastian/diff                        3.0.1    Diff implementation
sebastian/environment                 3.1.0    Provides functionality to handle HHVM/PHP environments
sebastian/exporter                    3.1.0    Provides the functionality to export PHP variables for visualization
sebastian/global-state                2.0.0    Snapshotting of global state
sebastian/object-enumerator           3.0.3    Traverses array structures and object graphs to enumerate all referenced objects
sebastian/object-reflector            1.1.1    Allows reflection of object attributes, including inherited and non-public ones
sebastian/recursion-context           3.0.0    Provides functionality to recursively process PHP variables
sebastian/resource-operations         1.0.0    Provides a list of PHP built-in functions that operate on resources
sebastian/version                     2.0.1    Library that helps with managing the version number of Git-hosted PHP projects
spinen/laravel-mail-assertions        0.3.4    PHPUnit mail assertions for testing email in Laravel.
swiftmailer/swiftmailer               v6.1.2   Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/console                       v4.1.4   Symfony Console Component
symfony/css-selector                  v4.1.4   Symfony CssSelector Component
symfony/debug                         v4.1.4   Symfony Debug Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v4.1.4   Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/finder                        v4.1.4   Symfony Finder Component
symfony/http-foundation               v4.1.4   Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v4.1.4   Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/polyfill-ctype                v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill for ctype functions
symfony/polyfill-mbstring             v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php72                v1.9.0   Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.2+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/process                       v4.1.4   Symfony Process Component
symfony/routing                       v4.1.4   Symfony Routing Component
symfony/translation                   v4.1.4   Symfony Translation Component
symfony/var-dumper                    v4.1.4   Symfony mechanism for exploring and dumping PHP variables
symfony/yaml                          v4.1.4   Symfony Yaml Component
theseer/tokenizer                     1.1.0    A small library for converting tokenized PHP source code into XML and potentially other formats
tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles     2.2.1    CssToInlineStyles is a class that enables you to convert HTML-pages/files into HTML-pages/files...
vlucas/phpdotenv                      v2.5.1   Loads environment variables from `.env` to `getenv()`, `$_ENV` and `$_SERVER` automagically.
webmozart/assert                      1.3.0    Assertions to validate method input/output with nice error messages.
```

Comment: Your project may have any dependencies that are not yet compatible with latest laravel.

Comment: What `composer show -i` shows to you?

Comment: @rob006 I have updated the question.. Please check..

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache` - maybe composer is using outdated packages data from packagist (although it should refresh it on every `composer update`). I tried your `composer.json` and I'm getting `5.6.37`, so this must be some caching issue.

Comment: @rob006.. I tried clearing cache.. Still the same..

Comment: Try `composer dumpautoload`, `composer clearcache`, `composer install`, `composer update`.

Comment: @Mtxz I have tried that as well, but no result at all.. Still the same..

Comment: Can you please tell us which command you used to install laravel ? becauase composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel project_name , everything works fine also it download latest stable build of laravel

Comment: @ViperTecPro Whenever I create a new laravel project, I create it with `laravel new <project-name>`..  By the way, I have clearly mentioned in my question that on new installation, I get the latest laravel project..

Answer (score 9):

Deleting `vendor` folder and running `composer install` did it for me.

Comment: Though brief, it was the answer that fixed my issue. Thanks @mi-ho!

Comment: Isn't it enough to just delete vendor/composer ?

Answer (score 0):

If deleting vendor and running `composer install` doesn't work, it might be a user-related issue. I was running composer install as the wrong user, and I got the same message. Running it as root fixed it.